# Inside the console.log dollar symbol isn't working

Tags: node.js

This is the code for greet.js where we pass 2 parameters via command line. But it isn't printing the proper results.

```
const firstname = process.argv[2];
const lastname = process.argv[3];
console.log('hello ${firstname} ${lastname}');
```

Comment: use `backticks` sign .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the **`** symbol instead of **'**

Take a look at *Template String*:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Answer (score -1):

```
const firstname = process.argv[2];
const lastname = process.argv[3];

console.log(`hello ${firstname} ${lastname}`);
```

use backticks not normal ' ';